# Undefined variable keyup function jQuery

Tags: jquery, undefined, typeerror, keyup

I think I have a simple question, but I can't figure it out. When I check my debugger, I get the following warning:

```
TypeError: $(...).val(...) is undefined
```

I want to add a class if a user types more then 3 characters in an input box. The script works, but the warning is annoying.

```
$(this).keyup(function(e) {

    var next_obj = jQuery("#kader .testnavigatie .checknext");
    inputidnummer = $(e.target).attr("id"); 

    if( $("#"+inputidnummer).val().length >= 3)   
    {       
        next_obj.removeClass("nextDisabled");
    }
    else {
        next_obj.addClass("nextDisabled");
    }
});
```

I need to grab the id when a user clicks on the input field.

Comment: And why not just `if (this.value.length >= 3) .. `

Comment: Can you give jsfiddle example?

Comment: Do all your inputs have an id specified?

Answer (score 0):

Change

`inputidnummer = $(e.target).attr("id");`

to

`inputidnummer = $(this).attr("id");`

**Edit**

And make sure you have attribute `id` in your input element. Because I believe that's what you are missing.

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qLtqum5t/)

Comment: That should be the same.

Comment: No problem..always there to help :)

Comment: For me it was Change

`inputidnummer = $(this).attr("id");`

to

`inputidnummer = $(e.target).attr("id");`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(selector).keyup(function(e) {

    var next_obj = $("#kader .testnavigatie .checknext");

    if( $(this).val().length >= 3)   
    {       
        next_obj.removeClass("nextDisabled");
    }
    else {
        next_obj.addClass("nextDisabled");
    }
});
```